# Clipping buffers to joined polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, clip, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I have two vector layers in QGIS:

1. a layer containing building outlines for houses
2. a layer containing parcel outlines for properties

I used a spatial join (join attributes by location) to connect the buildings and parcels. So I have a joined layer that contains each building plus the identifier for its associated parcel, i.e. the parcel that contains the building. All good so far.

Next, I need to draw a buffer of 100 ft. around each building but have that buffer clipped to the perimeter of the containing parcel. In other words, the buffer needs to be up to 100 ft. but also not extend beyond the edge of the property.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

You can follow these steps:

1. Buffer tool (distance: 100 ft)
2. Intersection tool (input layer: buffers, overlay layer: parcel)
3. Select by Location tool (select from: intersection, predicate: contain, by comparing to: building)
4. Invert Feature Selection (from Selection toolbar)

[image]

5. Toggle Editing  (from Digitizing toolbar), then click 'Delete Selected' button.

[image]

[image]

P.S. It can work for you but this is not the optimal solution. If you use a bigger value or buildings are so close to each other, it may not work.

Comment: I think the best solution is to use PyQGIS script.